# Is there a tool like Github Copilot which has a (Python 3) API?

Tags: python-3.x, comments, code-completion, github-copilot, aws-copilot

Tools like Github Copilot can generate/complete code and/or comments while typing within an IDE. It looks like they are limited to this use case.

However, I actually want to something similar to the following in any Python program:

```
import coolcopilotpackage as cop

comment = cop.generate("print('Hello World!') #")

print(comment)
```

The output should be looking like: `Prints the line 'Hello World!'`, completing the line of code that I started within the string given to `cop.generate`.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke Github Copilot programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76741410/how-to-invoke-github-copilot-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an API that is able to do almost exactly what you're asking for: https://github.com/B00TK1D/copilot-api.  It works as an HTTP API proxy instead of a native python module, but would be easily adaptable if you want.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you are looking for an API giving you access to a generative AI. Maybe take a look at OpenAI's API, they have a lot of models you can use in your own projects to build your own tools.

Comment: Do you have any specific model in mind?

Comment: You can use the playground to test the different models (e.g. text-davinci-003). Furthermore, you get explanations about the specific model and it‘s strength.