# How to invoke Github Copilot programmatically?

Tags: python, github-copilot

I am currently exploring GitHub Copilot, and I am interested in using it programmatically, i.e., invoking it from code. As I understand, GitHub Copilot is an IDE plugin, which makes me wonder how it can be automated or controlled programmatically. We know Copilot uses OpenAI models behind the scene as an LLM.

GitHub Copilot does not provide API access to control it programmatically.

Clarification:

- It's important to note that the plugin, once downloaded and installed, completes my code automatically. Copilot used the OpenAI models such as gpt-3.5 or gpt-4 behind the scene. I know very well the OpenAI chat or text completion models.**So that's not my question**
- My question is how to **capture the top three suggestions provided by Copilot** in an automated fashion.
- For example, for any given autocomplete task to Copilot, the task is to record the code suggestions and save them into a file.

Comment: How do you mean? Once you download it, it auto-complete's your code. Is it not doing that for you? I guess, please expand your question for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the vim plugin for copilot at https://github.com/github/copilot.vim ? This appears to be calling an LSP through a JSON-RPC api. The code isn't exactly easy to understand, but this would be a decent start, I believe.

Comment: @Ingo the most promising lines are [this](https://github.com/TerminalFi/LSP-copilot/blob/78c3f492f63ccfa755b1c7716f548333cfd0e1cc/plugin/plugin.py#L285) and [this](https://github.com/TerminalFi/LSP-copilot/blob/78c3f492f63ccfa755b1c7716f548333cfd0e1cc/plugin/utils.py#L178). I'm really lost in this so sharing to see if anybody can figure this stuff out. :^)

Comment: @lngo the reference you have given is a community implementation utilizing the Codex/GPT API. My question is, how can I capture the top three suggestions offered by Copilot?

Answer (score 12):

I just figured out how to invoke GitHub Copilot by the language server provided in [Copilot.vim](https://github.com/github/copilot.vim). I also referred to several community implementations like [copilot.lua](https://github.com/zbirenbaum/copilot.lua) and [LSP-copilot](https://github.com/TerminalFi/LSP-copilot) to understand that.

**TL;DR:** `Copilot.vim` invokes GitHub Copilot via a **language server**, which is contained in the `dist/` directory of its repository. Those vimscripts in `Copilot.vim` repository actually serve as a client to the language server.

The language server itself is written in Node.js, and uses stdio to communicate with the client. You can just download the `dist/` directory and run the language server by `node dist/agent.js`. However, just running the server by hand is hard to use, so I wrote a simple client in Node.js to invoke the language server and get the results.

This is a minimal example showing how to invoke GitHub Copilot programmatically via the language server extracted from `Copilot.vim`:

```js
// @ts-check

const { spawn } = require("node:child_process");

const server = spawn("node", ["agent.js"]);
// use `fork` in `node:child_process` is also OK
// const server = fork("agent.js", { silent: true });
// `{ silent: true }` is to make sure that data sent to stdio will be returned normally

/**
 * Send a LSP message to the server.
 */
const sendMessage = (/** @type {object} */ data) => {
  const dataString = JSON.stringify({ ...data, jsonrpc: "2.0" });
  const contentLength = Buffer.byteLength(dataString, "utf8");
  const rpcString = `Content-Length: ${contentLength}\r\n\r\n${dataString}`;
  server.stdin.write(rpcString);
};

let requestId = 0;
/** @type {Map<number, (payload: object) => void | Promise<void>>} */
const resolveMap = new Map();
/** @type {Map<number, (payload: object) => void | Promise<void>>} */
const rejectMap = new Map();

/**
 * Send a LSP request to the server.
 */
const sendRequest = (/** @type {string} */ method, /** @type {object} */ params) => {
  sendMessage({ id: ++requestId, method, params });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolveMap.set(requestId, resolve);
    rejectMap.set(requestId, reject);
  });
};
/**
 * Send a LSP notification to the server.
 */
const sendNotification = (/** @type {string} */ method, /** @type {object} */ params) => {
  sendMessage({ method, params });
};

/**
 * Handle received LSP payload.
 */
const handleReceivedPayload = (/** @type {object} */ payload) => {
  if ("id" in payload) {
    if ("result" in payload) {
      const resolve = resolveMap.get(payload.id);
      if (resolve) {
        resolve(payload.result);
        resolveMap.delete(payload.id);
      }
    } else if ("error" in payload) {
      const reject = rejectMap.get(payload.id);
      if (reject) {
        reject(payload.error);
        rejectMap.delete(payload.id);
      }
    }
  }
};

server.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  /** @type {string} */
  const rawString = data.toString("utf-8");
  const payloadStrings = rawString.split(/Content-Length: \d+\r\n\r\n/).filter((s) => s);

  for (const payloadString of payloadStrings) {
    /** @type {Record<string, unknown>} */
    let payload;
    try {
      payload = JSON.parse(payloadString);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to parse payload: ${payloadString}`, e);
      continue;
    }

    handleReceivedPayload(payload);
  }
});

const wait = (/** @type {number} */ ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

/* Main */
const main = async () => {
  // Wait for server to start
  await wait(1000);

  // Send `initialize` request
  await sendRequest("initialize", {
    capabilities: { workspace: { workspaceFolders: true } },
  });
  // Send `initialized` notification
  sendNotification("initialized", {});

  // Send `textDocument/didOpen` notification
  sendNotification("textDocument/didOpen", {
    textDocument: {
      uri: "file:///home/fakeuser/my-project/test.py",
      languageId: "python",
      version: 0, // The change count (i.e. version) of the document
      text: "def hello():\n" + "    print('hello, w",
    },
  });

  // Send `getCompletions` request to get completions at line 1, character 19
  // (i.e. after `print('hello, w`)
  const completions = await sendRequest("getCompletions", {
    doc: {
      version: 0, // Should be the same as the latest version of the document
      position: { line: 1, character: 19 },
      uri: "file:///home/fakeuser/my-project/test.py",
    },
  });
  console.log("Completions:", completions);
};

void main();
```

This example assumes you’ve already logged in to GitHub Copilot via something also using the language server like `Copilot.vim` or `LSP-copilot`. You can view [relevant implementations in LSP-copilot](https://github.com/TerminalFi/LSP-copilot/blob/master/plugin/constants.py) to see how to automate the login process programmatically (The `signInInitiate` request and `signInConfirm` request).

Then you can see something like this in your console:

[Results in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX3Pb.png)

If you’re not quite familiar with LSP, you can refer to [LSP specification](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-current/) to understand the meaning of each request and notification. Requests like `initialize` and `textDocument/didOpen` here are defined in the LSP specification, while `getCompletions` is a custom request defined by the GitHub Copilot language server. You can also use `textDocument/didChange` or `textDocument/didClose` to tell the language server that the document has been changed or closed (don’t forget to update the `version` field on each change).

Some other requests like `getCompletionsCycling` can provide more completions, you can also view `Copilot.vim` or relevant community implementations I mentioned above to see how to use them.

It should also be possible to write a Python client to invoke the language server, but the language server itself is written in Node.js, so it’s easier to write a Node.js client to invoke it.

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: I made an (unofficial) API: https://github.com/B00TK1D/copilot-api

I was inspired by @Snowflyt at how simple their API interface was, so I reverse engineered the Copilot vim plugin and associated API.  I matched the way they do OAuth (normal Github Apps aren't allowed Copilot access, so I just use Copilot's App ID).  This way, you don't have to rely on installing vim and the plugin and going through the setup process.

The repo linked includes a full self-hosted solution, that you can then call from whatever other functionality you want.  The first time you start it, you'll have to complete OAuth (enter provided code into link), and then after that it will automatically refresh all the auth tokens.  There are some more advanced features of Copilot that I haven't added yet, but it currently supports basic code completion prompting.

To answer exactly the question you asked - if you want to record the prompts and top responses from the Copilot plugin as you're using it, you can just wrap the `agent.js` file in the plugin with a logger, such as by using the following commands (assuming linux, and that you have the Vim copilot plugin installed):

1. `mv ~/.config/nvim/pack/github/start/copilot.vim/dist/agent.js ~/.config/nvim/pack/github/start/copilot.vim/dist/agent.orig.js`
2. Edit the file `~/.config/nvim/pack/github/start/copilot.vim/dist/agent.js`, and paste in the following code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const inLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('copilot-prompts.log', { flags: 'a' });
const outLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('copilot-suggestions.log', { flags: 'a' });

// Replace the path with the absolute path for agent.js
const agentScriptPath = '/root/.config/nvim/pack/github/start/copilot.vim/dist/agent.orig.js';

// Spawn a new process running agent.js with the absolute path
const agentProcess = spawn('node', [agentScriptPath]);

// Pipe stdin from the main script to the new process and log it
process.stdin.pipe(inLogStream);
process.stdin.pipe(agentProcess.stdin);

// Pipe stdout from the new process back to the main script's stdout and log it
agentProcess.stdout.pipe(outLogStream);
agentProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

// Handle process exit
agentProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(`Agent process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}`);
  inLogStream.end();
  outLogStream.end();
  process.exit();
});

// Handle errors
agentProcess.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`Error in agent process: ${err.message}`);
  inLogStream.end();
  outLogStream.end();
  process.exit(1);
});

// Handle main script stdin end
process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  // Close the stdin stream for the spawned process when main script stdin ends
  agentProcess.stdin.end();
});

// Handle main script exit
process.on('exit', () => {
  // Kill the spawned process when the main script exits
  agentProcess.kill();
});

// Handle main script termination
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  // Handle Ctrl+C to gracefully terminate both the main script and the spawned process
  process.exit();
});
```

3. Use copilot in vim as desired to generate logs.
4. View the prompts and suggestions in `~/copilot-prompts.log` and `~/copilot-suggestions.log`.

The output of these logs requires some parsing because they use JSON-RPC, but I'll let you decide exactly how you want to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub, doesn't publish their APIs publicly, as of yet.

However, it was speculated that GitHub Copilot used OpenAI's Codex (which is now deprecated). According to [this](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/code), you can use OpenAI's chat models for code completion, suggestion, etc. Though from my experience, the response time varies. Also, there's no guarante that it will output only code.

Check example below;

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {
     "role": "system",
     "content": "You are a helpful assistant. Assistant will output only and only code as a response."
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Write a Python function that takes as input a file path to an image, loads the image into memory as a numpy array, then crops the rows and columns around the perimeter if they are darker than a threshold value. Use the mean value of rows and columns to decide if they should be marked for deletion."
    }
  ],
  temperature=0,
  max_tokens=1024
)
```

Which will output;

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def crop_dark_borders(image_path, threshold):
    # Load the image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    # Convert the image to a numpy array
    image_array = np.array(image)
    
    # Calculate the mean value of each row and column
    row_means = np.mean(image_array, axis=1)
    col_means = np.mean(image_array, axis=0)

    ...
```

Edit; On a second thought, I wouldn't use `ChatCompletion` for this because the task is not chat based at all. Instead I would use [Completion](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) and supply the whole code file to it as an input. This has it's own limitations too. For example you wouldn't be able to provide to the model what's after the cursor.

Comment: However, this method doesn't capture the code completion suggestions that GitHub Copilot provided. The code snippet here merely demonstrates how to invoke OpenAI APIs. My requirement is to record the real-time suggestions provided by the GitHub Copilot plugin.

Comment: @Exploring Have you tried running your IDE's requests through a proxy, so that all the copilot API requests are logged? From there you can write your own API wrapper which will get the autocompletions from GitHub.

Comment: @Mave, was doing just that. Altough that might get you banned pretty quick, the top suggestions are not invoked on every key stroke I think.

Comment: @Exploring, your requirements are still unclear. Invoking the extension, invoking the API, record the real-time suggestions, these are all different tasks. I'm currently investigating how the API can be accessed, is that okay?

Comment: @doneforaiur the question is never how to invoke OpenAI API. Its just a simple python API call using OpenAI https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication.

Comment: My question is "how to automate Github Copilot and record its autocompletion."

Comment: Did some digging. Capturing packets was a no go for me, couldn't decrypt TLS. So I checked neovim's Copilot support. They mentioned to install Nodejs, that was odd. Then I've found an custom plugin [LSP-Copilot](https://github.com/TerminalFi/LSP-copilot/tree/78c3f492f63ccfa755b1c7716f548333cfd0e1cc) which requieres you to install [LSP](https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP) which uses JSON-RPC to communicate with the LSP-Copilot (and it's the same thing for neovim too). Skimmed through the source code for LSP-Copilot and it seems promising. Sharing this because somebody also might help.